# `No counter 'blx@maxsegment@<number>` error with `\includeonly`

Tags: biblatex, sectioning, include

A book manuscript that I used to compile successfully, first with all chapters, and then with only a few, using `\includeonly`, while retaining the `.aux` files from the full compilation, now results in an error: `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'blx@maxsegment@6' defined.`

To replicate the error, I have devised the following MWE with three component files so:

```
% test.tex
% MWE for `No counter 'blx@maxsegment@<number>` error with `includeonly`
%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,refsection=chapter,hyperref=auto]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%
% When the line below is commented out, error-free compilation results.
\includeonly{Two}
%
\begin{document}
%
\include{One}
\include{Two}
\include{Three}
%
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% One.tex
\chapter{One}\label{chap:one}
%%
% Two.tex
\chapter{Two}\label{chap:two}
%%
% Three.tex
\chapter{Three}\label{chap:three}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

When the `\includeonly` line is commented out, the file compiles successfully with `lualatex`. When the `\includeonly` line is uncommented, I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'blx@maxsegment@1' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.15 \include{One}
```

This issue has been recognized before and corrected in this [2014 issue on Github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/240) and this [later post on Github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/361).

I am unsure if its re-appearance is a regression bug, or due to my not keeping up with changes in the TeX ecosystem, or something else entirely. In any case, I would be grateful for a workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest biblatex tries to address some problems with includeonly (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1196) but still miss a few cases.

The problem here is that biblatex creates counters on the fly in the included files and then they are not defined if you use the \includeonly.

You could try this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber,refsection=chapter,hyperref=auto]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@refsection@i[#1]{%
  \endgroup
  \stepcounter{blx@maxsection}%
  \setcounter{refsection}{\value{blx@maxsection}}%
  \xifinlist{\the\c@refsection}\blx@allrefsections
    {}
    {\listxadd\blx@allrefsections{\the\c@refsection}}%
  \ifcsdef{blx@defaultrefcontexts@\the\c@refsection}
    {}
    {\global\cslet{blx@defaultrefcontexts@\the\c@refsection}\@empty}%
  \blx@providecounter{blx@maxsegment@\the\c@refsection}%
  \blx@providecounter{blx@sectionciteorder@\the\c@refsection}%
  %new provide counter in aux-file
  \if@filesw
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\blx@providecounter{blx@maxsegment@\the\c@refsection}}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\noexpand\blx@providecounter{blx@sectionciteorder@\the\c@refsection}}%
  \fi
  \blx@inf@refsec
  \blx@secinit
  \if@filesw
    \blx@auxwrite\@mainaux{}{%
      \string\abx@aux@refsection{\the\c@refsection}{\the\c@page}}%
    \ifblank{#1}
      {}
      {\let\blx@bibfiles\@empty
       % globals should be first as it might contain macros needed for others
       \forlistloop{\listadd\blx@bibfiles}\blx@bibfiles@global}%
       \blx@xsanitizeafter{\forcsvlist\blx@refsection@addfile}{#1}%
    \blx@refsection@ii
  \fi
  \blx@info{Setting label 'refsection:\the\c@refsection'}%
  \label{refsection:\the\c@refsection}%
  \endgroup}
  

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%
% When the line below is commented out, error-free compilation results.
%\includeonly{Two}
%
\begin{document}
%
\include{One}
\include{Two}
\include{Three}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ulrike Fischer. It works now!

Comment: Did not work for me. Going back to texlive 2021.

Comment: @StefanMüller I don't think that the patch is still needed, imho biblatex corrected the issue.

Comment: @StefanMüller, this is great! I think the only caveat is that we need to recompile the whole file before using the `includeonly`, just as `includeonly` should be used. Otherwise confusion might arise for files that are in progress while the tex system is updated (which happened to me, of course).